# How to handle crash in iOS (Swift) application using 'try', 'catch' and 'throw'?

Tags: ios, exception, crash, swift4

I am working on an iOS application. I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1.

I have to handle any crash in my iOS app and show a popup with crash details so that I can improve user experience in my application.

I don't have much knowledge of exception handling in iOS (Swift).

This is my code :

```
              do{

                    try self.fetchRecommendations()
                    print("Success! Yum.")

                } catch  {

                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

                }
```

I am calling method `'fetchRecommendations'` and I am putted a force crash code in this method block.

```
func fetchRecommendations()throws{


            try   fatalError()

}
```

On this line  `try   fatalError()` app should not be crashed and this line

```
print("\(error.localizedDescription)") should be executed.
```

But application is still crashing :
[image]

Comment: FatalError will stop the execution, it's not an exception. Please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538698-fatalerror

Comment: You can not use fatal error, what you need is  create func with throws ,   create  `Error`  subclass which  is a enum. throw error from enum

Comment: @ajeet: did our advices solve the issue? If so it would be great to set the checkmark on the correct answer. If not with what are you still struggling?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the apple [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) (*Representing and Throwing Errors*) about it. Instead of using the `fatalError` you should throw an error in your `fetchRecommendations()` function. That is why you put the signal word `throws` in there to signalize that this function can throw an error.

Errors are thrown using the `throw` word e.g:

```
throw VendingMachineError.insufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: 5)
```

All from the Apple documentation.

Comment: As palme said, you have to throw an error instead of calling `fatalError()`. You can find [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1050-magical-error-handling-in-swift) a good tutorial how to handle errors in Swift.